# How to re-name a ActiveRecord Model which can automatically change the table name in DB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Active Record model "car", I would like to change the name of this model to "train" **without** changing functionalities inside, that's **only** change the name. Also, the table name should be changed to "trains".

Is there any rails command can do that at onece? Or I have to manually change the name in side the class or migration? If I have to change manually, it's gonna be complicated, because I have to also change other models which have associations to my "car" model.

Any good suggestions?

Comment: What is the name of your corresponding database table? Is it cars or trains? Rails follow ORM-mapping so Active Record model classes should map into db table names.

Comment: My current table is "cars" I would like to change it's name to "trains".   Do you mean I need only to change the model class name to "Train"??

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would recommend the following:

1. Change manually the Active Record model class into Train
2. Make migration to change the database table name from cars to trains
3. Make good search to change references from Car to Train.

If you have constantly the need to change database table names, you might want to reconsider naming the tables more abstact way. Like in this case you could have table called vehicles and have the "type" field specifying the type (for instance: car or train).

Comment: Would it be wise to swap step one and two? Make the migration while the application actually runs but run it afterwards.

Comment: And is really changing the database name the way to go and not just the table?

Comment: @Petter, you're right. Only the table name, not the whole database. Made correction.

Answer (score 39):

I figured out the following way:

1, generate migration file:

```
rails generate migration rename_cars_to_trains
```

2. edit the created migration file to:

   ```
   class RenameCarsToTrains < ActiveRecord::Migration
     def self.up
       rename_table :cars, :trains
     end

     def self.down
       rename_table :trains, :cars
     end
   end
   ```
3. `rake db:migrate`

After these steps, the table name changed from cars to trains, then, I have to manually change the controller and views names and the associations...

If you have any more efficient way, let me know...

Comment: Yes, this is what I explained in my answer. I wouldn't care about finding more efficient way to something against Rails conventions. You'll just end up hurting yourself in the long run. Just keep your classes and table names following the Rails way and you'll do fine.

Answer (score 3):

I used following steps to rename my model

In sublime text:

1. press cmd + shift + find and choose case-sensitive search (see left buttons). It will search word in whole project
2. search and replace 'Cars' to 'Trains'
3. search and replace 'Car' to 'Train'
4. search and replace 'car' to 'train'
5. rails generate migration rename_cars_to_trains
6. manually change following **file names**

   - cars_controller
   - car_helper
   - Model/ car.rb
   - all related files in test folder
7. change folder name in views: cars to trains

Comment: This will ruin previous migration files.

Comment: @MoB assuming you mean it renames words within the previous migration files, simply use any modern editors ability to exclude a directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using RubyMine, go into the model, right click the class name > refactor and change the name. RubyMine will refactor everything and create a new migration for the database as well.